# og meta tags are not loading while sharing the url on somewhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meta, react-helmet, helmet.js

I am new to reactjs. I want to build the dynamic meta tags for the growth of SEO. I am writing the meta tags in my main page of the project but while sharing those tags are not loading.On inspecting I am able to see the og tags in the styles.I am using react helmet npm to build meta tags.Below is the code.

```
   <Helmet >
      <meta
        name="description"
        content="cbdshbcsdjvbsdjvdsjdfdf."
      />
      <meta property="og:title" content="xyzabc" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com" />
      <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://example.com/logo512.png" />
    </Helmet>
```

Comment: Are them placed directly in `index.html` or loaded by JavaScript? Edit: as I see, they are generated… so you should use something like Puppeteer to send a static preloaded version of these pages to spiders.

Comment: Consider getting familiar with "Server side rendering" phrase. @FedericoMoretti he's speaking about **dynamic** meta tags for SEO - hardcoding meta tags in index.html is something opposite. Anyways, look at the code. It's JSX.

Comment: @kinduser I see, using Helmet.js (that’s why I edited my comment): AFAIK, they don’t work unless a prerendered, static version of the page where they reside is available. As you mentioned, they need SSR to work.

Comment: I wrote meta tags in js file not in index.html. And I don't have server file. Is server file necessary to add separate meta tags to every page? I am able to add separate meta tags to separate pages but they aren't loading on page while sharing the url